# How to center text in a table drawn with kableextra?

Tags: r, center, kableextra

does someone know how to center the text in the table?

```
Mod <- c("1","1b","2","2b","3 ","3b")
Lag <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1")



dt <- data.frame(cbind(Mod,Lag))
dt %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Cambria")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Mod <- c("1","1b","2","2b","3 ","3b")
Lag <- c("1","1","1","1","1","1")



dt <- data.frame(cbind(Mod,Lag))
dt %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_classic(full_width = T, html_font = "Cambria")%>%row_spec(0:6, align = "c")
```